# In KDE tutorials, KXmlGuiWindow::setupGUI() doesn't display default menu bar of widget

Tags: menu, default, kde-plasma

I was trying out tutorials from this page
 [KDE techbase](https://techbase.kde.org/Development/Tutorials/Using_KXmlGuiWindow)
I noticed that, the code compiles and runs without errors, but the default toolbar with Settings, Help etc is not displayed in the output widget.I tried this out for next two tutorials too, but there is no menu bar.

The tutorial mentions that the KXmlGuiWindow::setupGUI() is used for this purpose. Can someone say what is wrong ?

Answer (score 0):

Solved the problem. I use KDE 4.14 framework in Ubuntu 14.04.Placing the appnameui.rc file in the Build folder manually helped. But, the settings, help menu still doesn't appear in widget above the textbox but rather in the menu bar in the top as it does for other apps in Ubuntu 14.04.